# Using compiled app on two different Ubuntu distribution versions

Tags: c++, ubuntu, curl

I need help and would be very grateful for any advice. I would like my application written in C++, which runs currently on Ubuntu 16.04, to also run on e.g. Ubuntu 20.04, and I would like to have one binary file that will run on both of these systems (only one compilation).

I copied the executable from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 and it failed to run, because on Ubuntu 20.04 I have cURL versions 7.68, while on Ubuntu 16.04 I have cURL versions 7.47. So I tried to upgrade the cURL version on Ubuntu 16.04 to the same as it is on Ubuntu 20.04 (7.68) by downloading the .deb file from Ubuntu 20.04 and copying them to Ubuntu 16.04, however, each time I installed such a package, the system informed me that it needed a different package with a newer version to install the one I'm currently trying to install. This process seemed to go on forever until I got to the point where one of these packages could not be installed.

Is this approach correct? Is it at all possible for an application that depends on libraries such as cURL, OpenSSL, etc. to run from only one file on two different Ubuntu distributions?

Comment: **Is this approach correct?** No, it's absolute incorrect.

Comment: libcurl is backward compatible and it's ABI is stable. I doubt it can be a reason of the issue of running your app on Ubuntu 20.

Comment: If it were so easy to just 'compile once, run everywhere' why do you think Canonical (essentially) rebuilds everything for every release?  (That is an approximation.  Builds are usually forward compatible unless eg shared library major.minor versions changes. Compiling and linking for reuse and distribution has its finer points, and distributions take care of it.  You also have [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) to create a personal PPA. I use one.)

Answer (score 2):

Link your library statically. Then all dependencies are part of the binary. Then it should run smoothly.

When you insist on using dynamic linking, you have to make sure that library locations and binary interfaces remain stable.